# Mysqli insert failing in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I had to learn php just today because of a data base assigment but I'm still having a little trouble.

I can't manage to insert a new row in my "cliente" table, I keep getting the "Error" message, can you guys help me fix this problem? thanks.

```
if($temp2=="no"){
            $idcon="NULL";
            $sql="INSERT INTO cliente VALUES('$idcli','$nombre','$ap_pat','$ap_mat','$dni','$nac','$edad','$direc','$cuenta','$vs','$idpac','$idcon');";
            if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New client registered";
            } else 
                echo "Error ";
```

I've tested all the variables to insert with an echo and they print the correct data, so i don't think the variables are the problem, maybe it's something with my syntax?

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: Missing column name `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)`

Comment: change `echo "Error ";` to `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $link->error);` to see the error message

Comment: Does variables inside single quotes work :-?

Comment: echo out $sql. It will be obvious. A little debugging here and there goes a long way

Comment: hey guys, thanks for answering, i added the column names and changed my echo to see what the error was, as Jens suggested, now i get this error: "Errormessage: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Comment: Improved structure and wording

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to solve your error

**First Method**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO cliente (column names here) VALUES('$idcli','$nombre','$ap_pat','$ap_mat','$dni','$nac','$edad','$direc','$cuenta','$vs','$idpac','$idcon');";
```

you have 12 column names, so add then wrt to values.

Make sure you pass the values and column names in correct order.

See syntax for insert query [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm)

**Second Method**

There is no need to pass column names always, but

values you are passing should be in the same order as that in your database.

If you are jumbling the order of column names, your values will not be inserted properly. And error might arise if the `column name datatype mismatches`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's mysql error.this table has a foreign key for other table.you should insert that table first.

By the way,do you really need a foreign key for your project?

Comment: Hey, yes I found out there was no foreign key to match in the other table, so i inserted it first. now it works like a charm! about the FK, yes i'm working with a lot of tables and most of them are related in some way, so i need the FK for this project. thanks for helping!